# Two screen merging with each other even with switch

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So two of my screens are merging with each other, Screen 1 (Home screen) is partially appearing on Screen 2 (Not home screen), I'm using switch and exact attribute but that still is not solving my problem, My code is like this:

```
function App() {
    let routes = (
       <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact>
                <HomeScreen />
            </Route>
        </Switch> 
        
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/admin/products' exact>
                <AdminPanelProductChanger />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    )
    return routes
}
```

Making all routes children of the same switch gives me the same result

Answer (score 1):

They need to be children of the same `<Switch>`:

```
function App() {
    let routes = (
       <Switch>
            <Route path='/' exact>
                <HomeScreen />
            </Route>
            <Route path='/admin/products' exact>
                <AdminPanelProductChanger />
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    )
    return routes
}
```

Comment: That still gives me the same result

Comment: @SnaccOvenFlour could you make a codesandbox?